# Jquery Documentation locally

Tags: jquery

Well my question sums it up . actually i often find [Jquery Site](http://api.jquery.com/) , to be quite a great resource , so i'd like to have it locally on my system . is it possible  ??

if it is , it would be of great great help . it might sound a bit odd that i want the entire website to be accessible locally , but its necessary due to some reason .

i found out  that for mac there is a application called Dash and also heard that Jquery has a project on github that can be downloaded , but is it as explanatory and expansive as the online model ?

also i use windows , so is there any application for windows that does what dash does  for mac .

Also i am aware that there are applications that can download entire sites , i have no idea what such applications are called , this would really be my last resort , but suggestions to such kind of an application are welcome .

Thanks .

Comment: Dash is really nice and it's the exact documentation that you find online.

Comment: @limelights i know but its only for Mac , is't it ? i desperately need the Jquery documentation locally and most importantly , i need it to be reliable , jst like dash , once again , if the only option for windows is to download the entire website , i don't have a problem doing it .

Comment: check this - [Where can I download the jQuery API documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763/where-can-i-download-the-jquery-api-documentation)

Comment: use this link to download offline tutorial http://thetechme.com/2014/09/download-offline-w3-school-2014-free-latest-version-for-pcmobile/

Comment: yeah will try those , that was helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow to setup jQuery Documentation locally is available [here](http://contribute.jquery.org/web-sites/#workflow)

> Local Development
>   In order to iterate on site content and design in the same way that jQuery team members do, we encourage you to setup a local WordPress instance using [jquery-wp-content](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-wp-content) as described in its README.
>
> These setup instructions apply to all jQuery Foundation websites with
>   public content repositories. For the sake of the rest of this example,
>   we'll assume you want to work on the content and style of
>   contribute.jquery.org. Please substitute the URL of whichever site you
>   are actually working on, as appropriate.
>
> Once you get jquery-wp-content working, you should be able navigate to
>   a site in your browser that looks exactly like the live site, only
>   without any content. If you setup jquery-wp-content using Vagrant,
>   then the URL would be http://vagrant.contribute.jquery.org.
>
> Now we need to populate your local WordPress with the content from the
>   contribute.jquery.org repo.
>
> 1. Fork the contribute.jquery.org repository on GitHub by clicking the "Fork" button.
> 2. Clone your forked repository to wherever you'd like, but not inside
>      of your WordPress and jquery-wp-content directories. -- git clone
>      https://github.com/YourUsername/contribute.jquery.org.git
> 3. Enter the directory where you cloned the repo -- cd contribute.jquery.org
> 4. Install grunt-cli (if you haven't already) -- npm install -g
>      grunt-cli
> 5. Install local build dependencies -- npm install
> 6. Copy the config-sample.json file to config.json in the same directory -- cp config-sample.json config.json
> 7. Edit config.json to use the URL, username, and password for your
>      local WordPress network. If you're using the Vagrant setup, then the
>      URL is http://vagrant.contribute.jquery.org.
> 8. Build and deploy the files to your local WordPress -- grunt deploy
>
> At this point your local WordPress should be populated with the
>   contribute.jquery.org content.

Just replace `contribute.jquery.org` instances with `api.jquery.org`. You'll need Git http://git-scm.com/ and npm from [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)